# Content is overlapping with Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Create a html page for mobile some part of content is showing on Menu bar.

Only the bottom content is showing on menu bar how to avoid it ?

and also I want to disable scroll-bar when menu button is clicked & enable when content is touched using Mobile.
I tried below code but its disabliling but not enabling scrollbar when content screen is clicked on mobile :(

My Javascript :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    scrollTopPos = $( document ).scrollTop();
    allowScrolling = true;

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if(allowScrolling === false) {
            $( document ).scrollTop( scrollTopPos );
        } else {

        }
    });

    $( "#mobile-toggle" ).click(function() {
         $('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');   
        $("#divCls").css('display','None')      
    });

   $(document).on('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        showDiv()
    });   
});
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('divCls').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Post you HTML and CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without the full code, but in terms of keeping the menu at the front you can just use CSS to se the Z-index of the DIV. In terms of the scroll, add a CSS rule trigger within your JavaScript to set Overflow to Hidden then set it back to scroll when you click the close button.

Also, if only parts are spilling over then be weary of the page size, if you're using a slide in menu that is hidden to the side then slides the whole page over, then mobile users can swipe it shut but the open button will not work unless you use the jquery swipe functionality so again, the z index and a bit of doodling with the script to make the menu sit over the page would fix this. Again, more script would be handy :P